# Databricks - Selenium - Open browser tab with

Tags: selenium

I have successfully installed Selenium in Databricks and can import the Python selenium and webdriver. On my local computer once I run the Selenium get command a separate browser windows open where I can see what Selenium is doing.

However, when running the same script on Databricks there is unfortunately no window opening. I am wondering if this is at all possible. I found some options like

```
browser.execute_script('''window.open("http://bings.com","_blank");''')
```

or

```
 add_experimental_option
```

but these options did not work.

I am currently using the following options on Databricks:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType
import pandas as pd

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# installed driver
chrome_driver = "/tmp/chromedriver1/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver, options=chrome_options)
```

Has someone an idea how this could work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't open since you are using headless browser. See the below line from your code :-

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
```

Having said that, it will execute the Python-Selenium bindings instruction, you have. You can try to print the page title like this :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver, options=chrome_options) 
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
```

should print `google.com` title in the console.

Comment: Yes this printing the Headline. But I would like to have a new window to appear in which the Google Search page appears (as I enter google.com). Adding this company does not run as intended. I would like to see what Selenium is doing given that I want to do further Tests.

Comment: See, generally that is not a headless mode, so if you take out `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')` line from your code, and if you were using pycharm or any IDE in your local environment, you would see Selenium launching a browser with the specified set of instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Executing scripts with selenium in notebook on Databrics does not give you such option.
If it opens and works well without pyvirtualdisplay - great)
But I had to install

```
% pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

And then

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(600, 600))
display.start()
```

Workaround to see the page you opened:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
displayHTML(driver.page_source)  # <------- display html page in cell output
```

to find element on the page:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(text(), 'Search')]")
button.click()
```

I often open needed page on separate window on local machine and check html source to find needed keys for html-elements to use in code